# How to extract a certain element from a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, extract, element

For example:

```
d = [{'symbol': 'ETH', 'available': '1'}, {'symbol': 'DOGE', 'available': '4'} , {'symbol': 'USD', 'available': '10'}]
```

I need to extract the available USD which is 10 in the above dictionary, could you please provide me with a proper code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next()` built-in method:

```py
out = next(dct["available"] for dct in d if dct["symbol"] == "USD")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your language is python you can do:

```
print([x for x in d if d['symbol'] == 'USD'][0]['available'])
```

Do keep in mind that `USD` must exist in the list for it to work.